# How do I update an existing text file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file that contains 16,328,530 lines.  Each line is 830 bytes long (828 bytes of data + 2 bytes for crlf).  So the file size is 13 Gig.

I want to be able to read the file line by line and if a certain condition is meet to update the data in the line of data and then rewrite the data to the existing file.

Is there a way to do this in VB.NET?

Thanks

Comment: for readign line by line  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: You don't "Edit" files, you have to recreate them. So, you need to iterate through the file and if you find the situation you are looking for, start again but this time writing every line to another file and when you hit the line(s) you need to edit, make the change and write that line to the new file, then continue writing each line.

Comment: text file are not random access - you cannot update just a piece of it.  it will have to be written back out entirely.  Since you probably cannot load that much data into memory, you would have to write to a new file.  that much data should probably be in a database.

Comment: using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    stream.Seek(1000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
}

Comment: This design is very, very brittle.  If the task is to update 5 of the 16 Million lines, you have to copy all of them to a new file.  If something goes wrong, you risk loosing all the data.  Each line ought not have to be handled to process some subset (like the 5).  For that reason, a database would be a much better solution (in addition, you would not have to parse each line or whatever you are doing).

Comment: You will find this article helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903289(v=vs.71).aspx it´s talking about working with fixed length records as you like to do. Despite all other comments, IT IS POSSIBLE to edit records.

Comment: So I tested both the FileStream and FileOpen methods and was able to get both to work.  Does anyone know if there are benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: @RandyG [`FileOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afh37kh8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and related functions are "provided for backward compatibility and may affect performance", so stick with `FileStream`.

Answer (score 0):

So now here is the example code .... I tested this in the last few minutes (in an empty Sub Main()

```
Module MainModule

    <VBFixedString(830)> Public recordBuffer As String

    Sub Main()

        Dim fn As Integer = FreeFile()

        FileOpen(fn, "c:\temp\test.data", OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Shared, 830)

        For i As Integer = 100000 To 100020
            ' This ensures the buffer is of correct size, even if file is shorter (= new records will be added)
            recordBuffer = Space(830) 
            FileGet(fn, recordBuffer, i, True)
            recordBuffer = recordBuffer.ToUpper()
            ' Here I cut away all bad things that could happen to a string :-/
            FilePut(fn, recordBuffer.Substr(0, 830), i, True)
        Next i

        FileClose(fn)

   End Sub

End Module
```

I tested this with a file, on different portions of it. And the file will be extended, if you put a record where no record was before (therefor the Space(830) assignment to recordBuffer prior to the FileGet)